# DirectX: Passing a array pointer to vertex structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures, directx

I noticed some strangeness when passing a `VERTEX` structure to a buffer. At first I thought it was a faulty custom function for reading into .obj files, but debugging further narrowed the problem. Take for instance:

```
struct VERTEX{ 
    XMFLOAT3 Translation; 
    D3DXCOLOR Color;
};
```

and it's instance:

```
VERTEX foo[] = {
        {XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)}, 
        {XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)}, 
        {XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(2.0f, 0.9f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f)},
     };
```

Work perfectly when passed into a vertex buffer. 
Dynamically creating an array instance of the structure yields strange results. I'll see one vertex show up, or none. Here's an example, imagine `foo` as being a function returning a [working] `VERTEX*` array of vertices:

```
VERTEX *bar= new VERTEX[barsize];
VERTEX foo[] = {
        {XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)}, 
        {XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)}, 
        {XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(0.9f, 0.0f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)},
        {XMFLOAT3(2.0f, 0.9f, 0.0f), D3DXCOLOR(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f)},
     };
bar=foo;
```

And later on...

```
memcpy(MappedResource.pData, &bar, sizeof(bar));
```

Am I doing something funny trying to access the data that `foo` points to, such that only the first set of coordinates get passed in?

*edit: When writing this post, foo and bar got mixed. This post now shows the correct example.

Comment: your code is very confused, what does foo do? you said it is a function, but it is an array in your code, and foo=bar will get an uninitialized value.

Comment: I just edited the post, sorry. I dulled down the problem a bit. The original code has a function that parses an obj file for vertices. It returns a `VEXTEX*` array(represented as `VERTEX foo[]`), which is copied over to bar. I noticed that a `VERTEX` array works fine, but when I allocate using `new`, I can access the elements in the new array, but D3D can't - it seems to just draw a single point. I believe it to be a pointer issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

> bar=foo;
>
> memcpy(MappedResource.pData, &bar, sizeof(bar));

bar is a pointer of VERTEX, not a array of VERTEX, sizeof(bar) == 4 on x86 machine, so you will not get all the element copied.

you can first count how many Vertex element you need, and then when using memcpy, use sizeof(VERTEX) * vertex_count.

Comment: How would I reference the array `sizeof()` being pointed to:
`memcpy(MappedResource.pData, &bar, sizeof(&*bar));`?

Comment: How can I get the `sizeof(VERTEX)` in memory through it's pointer `VERTEX*`

Comment: Thanks. It was making me crazy. 
I found this too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: You definitely helped my understanding of my "missing memory" a bit further.